# can i ask about the software recommendations here?

Tags: discussion

can i ask an question regarding software recommendations for database administration here?
for e.g **can anyone suggest me an  tool to monitor the random changes occurs in database administration** ,
can i ask the questions regarding software recommendations proceeded here in main site?
i proceed this post since before posting a question i would like to hear whether it can be posted here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

There is not a blanket ban on this sort of question, but you must stay within the guidelines in the faq:

> - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face
> - Your questions should be reasonably scoped.
> - If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here

and particularly:

> - avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

In practice if your question is specific enough, it will probably be ok, so "What is **the best** tool to monitor **DDL** changes on an **Oracle** database (version 11.2)?" is good, but "What tools are there to monitor changes on databases?" is bad.

Facts like your database version number will likely be provided in the form of [tags](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) rather than spelled out in the question title but that is an aside.

Comment: Well-said, Jack! :)

Answer (score 4):

You may also ask questions like that in chat, especially on [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap).  Simpler questions which wouldn't fit in the guidelines described by JackDouglas are often asked and answered there.